# How can i build batch the request and understand the response with help ZStream (ZIO)?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-streams

I have api that gets such request:

```
case class UsersRequest(ids: List[Long])
```

and returns such response:

```
case class UsersInfoResponse(info: List[Info])
case class Info(userId: Long, info: String)
```

also, i have methods that send this request and create user:

```
def createUser(id: Long): IO[Throwable, User] = {
 getUserInfo(id)
   .map(info => User(id, info))
}

def getUserInfo(id:Long): IO[Throwable, String] = {
   here i call grpc service
   service.getUserInfo(UsersRequest(List(id)))
}
```

I want:

1. write ZStream that create ids batch
2. every 1 sec takes 10 ids and creates UsersRequest
3. gets UsersInfoResponse
4. using id understands what info must gets
5. return info

So that I can do it i should create something similar:

```
def getUserInfo(id:Long): IO[Throwable, String] = {
   Stream
      .fromQueue()
      .groupedWithin(10, Duration.Zero)
      .????
      .runDrain
      .forkManaged

   AND

      p <- Promise.make[Throwable, String]
      interrupted <- Promise.make[Nothing, Unit]
      env <- ZIO.environment[R]
}
```

I don't how i can do it.
How can build batch and send the request and after match by id get result?

Comment: 1. I think you mean to write def createUser(id: Long): IO[Throwable, User] = {
 getUserInfo(id)
   .map(info => Info(id, info))
}
not User, you didnt define such a class
2.Also why are you using a List inside UserRequest if you only wish to hold one long?
3.where is the source of the Id's?

Comment: This is just example, i want to be able to create batch from single request uses promise and Stream.fromQueue(), as it do kafka producer may be. But i do not want use callback.

Comment: I want to hoard batch from single requests and when i have certain amount then i will send batch request, but i should understand response and do mapping with single request